# Paperclip: Skip original file from uploading and accept url

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am uploading original video file that is uploaded through Paperclip directly onto S3 via iOS device.

I am able to get the folder path to original and also the file is successfully being uploaded through device.

After uploading device sends and API call to the server with video parameter as : VIDEO_URL

The request received at server end processes the video and again creates a file in the :original path which I do not want. I just want the style images to be uploaded from the video url. Any way to restrict the video file from processing as original ???

Model

```
has_attached_file :video, styles: {
    timestamped: { processors: %i[ timestamper ] },
    small: ['640x', :jpeg],
    medium: ['750x', :jpeg],
    large: ['1242x', :jpeg]
  }
```

Comment: did you try the reprocess method...It accepts style arguments `dummy.avatar.reprocess!(:medium)`

Comment: Reprocess... Sorry could you please elaborate

Comment: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/spec/paperclip/storage/s3_spec.rb#L448-L465

Comment: @VamsiKrishna Will this help in restricting original file upload which I have already uploaded directly through S3 and just uploads the thumbnails

Comment: Yes...That is what the gem issue says...You can have a look at this issue for more information https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1804

Comment: But a concern. My record is created only when the thumbnails have been created. I just want to edit the above code in such a way that original file is not processed so as to reduce the S3 load cost. and reprocess will work on a model record that is available in the database.